# CodeIgniter: what makes a good model

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

What makes a good MVC model in CodeIgniter. What my 'user' model does now is basically using the same active record functions from the database library. The only difference is that you don't need to specify the database table and just do:

```
$this->usermodel->where('username','test'),
$user = $this->usermodel->get();
```

This feels kinda awkward, since its not making it 'a lot easier'.

Another way I thought of was making the user model like an user object with a load function. But this is not efficient when loading more than 1 user.

Can I get some tips from you guys? Thanks.

Comment: Why did my question get degraded? Was it not clear enough?

Comment: You may know this, but the ideal Model-Controller setup should be fat Models, and Skinny controllers.  Do all the "thinking" in the model! :)

Comment: Abstractly, i'd say: a good database schema.

Answer (score 2):

A good tip would be, not letting model an view talk with each other straight, you always(or when it's possible) have to use controller to do this kind of communication.

I've heard also the opinion that it's a bad practice to have logic inside your models...I don't know if this is true but it's a rule I have broken lots of times(if somebody knows more about the subject please correct me).

And of course always have in mind that model should be reusable , so I try to give general solution to some problems and not application specific...on the other hand controller seems to be the throwaway component so this is where you should  do ugly  stuff that will never be used in other projects...

Hope it helps a little

Comment: I was not asking about MVC, I was asking about model specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'a lot easier' comes in when you are working with large sets of data, and have many complex queries to make. As I understand it, if you are working on something that is relatively simple, you can forego the model and make your db calls from within the controller. There isn't a 'best practice' per se, but rather personal preference.

The MVC architecture allows for better compartmentalizing of code, and can allow for better structure and re-use of code, but you needn't follow the MVC idea to the letter to accomplish many things -- again it comes down to preference.

Comment: I know what's the point of using the MVC design pattern. I was just asking for some tips about the model structure itself.

Answer (score 0):

The point is to abstract all of your application logic into Models and use Controllers simply for 'controlling' your web interface and mediating between the web interface and the models.

The models are your program proper you should be able to pretty easily completely redesign the user interface without affecting the application models.